# Relating entries/users with a custom element (or custom database table)

Tags: relations, elementtype

Let's say I have a bunch of **Craft entries** and **Craft users** that I need to relate to **another custom database table**. How would one approach this?

Would I be correct in thinking that my plugin will need to:

1. Create a custom element type which ties back to this custom database table
2. Create a custom field type, based on an existing field type such as `EntriesFieldType.php` and is able to handle the GUI actions for creating the relationship
3. Apply that field type to any edit forms which need to relate to my custom table

Is there anything I'm missing, or any gotchas in implementing the above?